# Selection not happening properly in navbar in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a html page with persistent footers using jquery mobile.This is the code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Test</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
                Home Page
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="pFooter">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home" data-icon="custom" class="ui-btn-active">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#page2" data-icon="grid">Second page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#page3" data-icon="star">Third page</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="page2">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Test</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
                Second page
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="pFooter">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home" data-icon="custom">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#page2" data-icon="grid"  class="ui-btn-active">Second page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#page3" data-icon="star">Third page</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="page3">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Test</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
                Third page
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="pFooter">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home" data-icon="custom">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#page2" data-icon="grid">Second page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#page3" data-icon="star" class="ui-btn-active">Third page</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The following use case illustrates the problem I am facing

1) Click second button in the navbar.

2) Second page content comes properly and the second button stays selected.

3) Click first button in the navbar.

4) **Home page content comes properly,but first button is not in selected state**

5) Again click first button.

6) Now first button is in selected state.

You can see this in action here - http://jsfiddle.net/tKMgd/

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I would switch your accepted answer to Yoan DM's answer. It is now the correct way to fix this issue in the most recent version of jQM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this issue, I know this is not the most beautiful solution but you can bind to the `pageshow` (or `pagebeforeshow`) event for each page and have the button's state changed on `pageshow`:

```
$(document).delegate('div[id*="events"]', 'pagebeforeshow',function(event){
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_link').attr('class','ui-btn-active ui-btn ui-btn-up-a');
});
```

In this example any page that has "events" in the id will make the link with the id of the page plus "_link" (e.g. "events_link") active. You can use code similar to this to make each page add the active class to the proper link in your footer:

```
$(document).delegate('#home, #page2, #page3', 'pagebeforeshow',function(event){
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_link').addClass('ui-btn-active');
});
```

NOTE: The above sample of code requires that the links in your footers have the ids: `home_link`, `page2_link`, `page3_link`. Here is an updated version of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tKMgd/5/

Answer (score 2):

The solution : http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/03/31/jquery-mobile-alpha-4-released/

add the class ui-state-persist with ui-btn-active

page2

Answer (score 0):

Add the "ui-state-persist". See the example in the code below:

```
<div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#page1" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page2" data-icon="star">Favorite</a></li>
</ul>
```